# Convert value of money

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting, worksheet-function

I can't seem to find this or I am not searching for the correct term. I am simply trying to change money to long string. The data being pulled to D cell has it as `$7.5K` for example. I would like to remove the dollar symbol and write the decimal to long form so change `$7.5K` to `7500`.

A few notes:
-ALL the data is above $1K so nothing will be below that amount. 
-money has no ONEs or TENs value so these are always `00`.

Not sure if I can automate this or make it easier to convert these values using the Find/Replace.

Comment: So remove the dollar sign and `K` using string operations, convert the remaining portion of the string to a floating point number, and multiply it by 1000.

Comment: thanks @pnuts that made sense lol but when i go to search only in D it changes all the data to #### not sure why. i dont have hardly any experience with excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the true /underlying value is a number, simply reformat as Number with no decimal places. If a text string either:

> Replace `K` by `*1000` and then `$` by `=` and format to suit

or, as suggested by @Ken White, apply a formula such as:

```
=1000*SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"$",""),"K","")
```

again with suitable formatting.

Comment: perfect! @ken suggestion in your post worked perfect! i was trying to do find/replace but it was not working at all. this made it much easier thank you!